# How to read access-log hosts with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have such entries:

```
e179206120.adsl.alicedsl.de
safecamp-plus-2098.unibw-hamburg.de
p5B30EBFE.dip0.t-ipconnect.de
```

and I would like to match only the main domain names like

```
alicedsl.de
unibw-hamburg.de
t-ipconnect.de
```

I tried this `\.\w+\.\w+\.\w{2,3}` but that matches `.adsl.alicedsl.de`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `[^.]+\.\w+$`

[See it work](http://regex101.com/r/qK7aE2)

Or, in Python:

```
import re

tgt='''\
e179206120.adsl.alicedsl.de
safecamp-plus-2098.unibw-hamburg.de
p5B30EBFE.dip0.t-ipconnect.de'''

print re.findall(r'([^.]+\.\w+$)', tgt, re.M | re.S)
# ['alicedsl.de', 'unibw-hamburg.de', 't-ipconnect.de']
```

Regex explanation:

1. `[^.]+` 1 or more characters EXCEPT a literal `.`
2. `\.`  literal `.` It needs the `\` because it would be any chaarcter to regex if not used
3. `\w+`  1 or more characters in the ranges of `[a-z] [A-Z] [0-9] [_]` *Potentially* a better regex for TLD's in ASCII is `[a-zA-Z]+` since there aren't any **old** TLD's that are not ASCII. If you want to manage newer [Internationalized TLD's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_country_code_top-level_domain), you need a different regex.
4. `$` assertion for the end of the line

You should know that you definition of TLD's is incomplete. For example, this regex approach will break on the legitimate url of [bbc.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk) and many others that include a common SLD. Use a library if you can for more general applicability. You can also use the [mozilla list of TLD and SLD's](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1) to know when it is appropriate to include two periods in the definition of host.

Comment: Could you explain your regex?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following with your given data.

```
[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/nC7gU8)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have restrictions on using external libraries, check out TLD extract library

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract

```
import tldextract
for input in ["e179206120.adsl.alicedsl.de", "safecamp-plus-2098.unibw-hamburg.de", "p5B30EBFE.dip0.t-ipconnect.de"]:
    input_tld = tldextract.extract(input)
    print input_tld.domain+"."+input_tld.suffix
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need Regex for this.  A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) will be far more efficient:

```
>>> mystr = """
... e179206120.adsl.alicedsl.de
... safecamp-plus-2098.unibw-hamburg.de
... p5B30EBFE.dip0.t-ipconnect.de
... """
>>> [".".join(line.rsplit(".", 2)[-2:]) for line in mystr.splitlines() if line]
['alicedsl.de', 'unibw-hamburg.de', 't-ipconnect.de']
>>>
```

Also, if you want it, here is a reference on [Python's string methods](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) (it explains `str.splitlines`, `str.rsplit`, and `str.join`).

---

If you run a speed test using [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit), you will see that the list comprehension is much faster:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> mystr = """
... e179206120.adsl.alicedsl.de
... safecamp-plus-2098.unibw-hamburg.de
... p5B30EBFE.dip0.t-ipconnect.de
... """
>>> def func():
...     import re
...     re.findall(r'([^.]+\.\w+$)', mystr, re.M | re.S)
...
>>> timeit("func()", "from __main__ import func") # Regex's time
51.85605544838802
>>> def func():
...     [".".join(line.rsplit(".", 2)[-2:]) for line in mystr.splitlines() if line]
...
>>> timeit("func()", "from __main__ import func") # List comp.'s time
12.113929004943316
>>>
```